# Getting "option" missing error with xUnit2 target in FAKE build file

Tags: f#, f#-fake, xunit2

When I add the example xUnit2 target to my FAKE build file, I'm getting this error:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 
>           string option
>        but here has type
>           string

Target Example from [FAKE xunit2 documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-testing-xunit2.html)

```
Target "Test" (fun _ ->
    !! (testDir @@ "xUnit.Test.*.dll")
      |> xUnit2 (fun p -> {p with HtmlOutputPath = (testDir @@ "xunit.html")})
)
```

The Visual Studio is highlighting the `(testDir @@ "xunit.html")` section of the code.

I understand that it's expecting two parameters, but I don't know enough F# yet to figure out how to fix the problem:

Prior to including the xUnit target, my FAKE build was working fine.
I've added `open Fake.Testing.XUnit2` to the build file and I get no error with the xUnit2 reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the error is that the type of `HtmlOutputPath` is

```
HtmlOutputPath : string option
```

In Fake I believe that `@@` does `Path.Combine` so `testDir @@ "xunit.html` should have type string.

To get the types to match, you can use

```
HtmlOutputPath = Some(testDir @@ "xunit.html")
```

This suggests that the documentation for FAKE is incorrect.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but isn't the problem exactly that `testDir @@ "xunit.html"` is `string`, but should be `string option`?

Comment: yep, but apparently some magic happens when you do the `open` on the namespace - that part I can't figure out (since OP states that it works after an `open`

Comment: Actually, I just want to make it clear that I added the `open` to the top of the FAKE file.  So I have a valid reference to the xUnit2 code.

Comment: Oh, in that case `HtmlOutputPath = Some(testDir @@ "xunit.html")` should work, but maybe the documentation needs an update

Comment: `Some(...)` was the answer! If you update the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for opening the FAKE ticket!